# UTC displaying wrong times using moment.js

Tags: javascript, timezone, momentjs, offset

I am trying to save a date and time for different time zones. I have changed my time zone in my chrome dev tools for testing purposes as follows

[image: dev tools]

So for testing, I am trying to save a date time for London as '2023/04/21 23:55' when I save this datetimeoffset into my DB it gets stored as `'2023-01-30T23:55:00+02:00'`

but now when I try to read the format the date is as follows

```
var test = Moment(date); //'2023-01-30T23:55:00+02:00'
test = test.utc(true);
var format = "yyyy/MM/DD HH:mm";
return test.format(format);
```

it returns the date `2023/01/30 21:55`. Why is it removing the 2 hours?

Comment: "when i save this datetimeoffset into my db it gets stored as '2023-01-30T23:55:00+02:00'" - that seems like a problem to start with then, given that the UTC offset of London in January is zero, not 2 hours.

Comment: I think this is an issue with using forward slashes, which are interpreted differently than dashes. Does my answer to the question I linked above answer your question?

Comment: @MichaelM. i tried changing the slashes to the dashes but it didnt work gives me the same time of 21:55

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that your datetimeoffset has a timezone associated with it (`+02:00`). The `2023-01-30T23:55` part of your timestamp is **not** UTC time, it is local time, and the `+02:00` signifies the offset of that timezone.

I'm not sure how you're saving that time in the first place, you probably forgot to specify the timezone as UTC. For example, if the date was created with `Moment('2023-01-30T23:55:00')`, then it that time will be intepreted as 23:55:00 on 2023-01-30 **in the system's timezone**, not UTC. To fix this, you need to use the `Moment.utc('2023-01-30T23:55:00')`.